# TypeError while using Pool from multiprocessing (python 3.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-3.7

I'm trying to sum up the sizes of all files in a directory including recursive subdirectories. The relevant function (`self._count`) works totaly fine if I just call it once. But for large amounts of files I want to use `multiprocessing` to make the program faster. Here are the relevant parts of the code.

`self._sum_dict` sums the values of the same keys of the given dicts up.
`self._get_file_type` returns the category (key for `stats`) the file shall be placed.
`self._categories` holds a list of all possible categorys.
`number_of_threats` specifies the number of workers thal shall be used.
`path` holds the path to the directory meantioned in the first sentence.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def _count(self, path):
    stats = dict.fromkeys(self._categories, 0)
    try:
        dir_list = os.listdir(path)
    except:
        # I do some warning here, but removed it for SSCCE
        return stats

    for element in dir_list:
        new_path = os.path.join(path, element)

        if os.path.isdir(new_path):
            add_stats = self._count(new_path)
            stats = self._sum_dicts([stats, add_stats])
        else:
            file_type = self._get_file_type(element)
            try:
                size = os.path.getsize(new_path)
            except Exception as e:
                # I do some warning here, but removed it for SSCCE
                continue

            stats[file_type] += size

    return stats

files = []
dirs = []
for e in dir_list:
    new_name = os.path.join(path, e)
    if os.path.isdir(new_name):
        dirs.append(new_name)
    else:
        files.append(new_name)

with Pool(processes=number_of_threats) as pool:
    res = pool.map(self._count, dirs)

self._stats = self._sum_dicts(res)
```

I know, that this code won't consider files in `path`, but that is something that I can add easily add. When execuding the code I get the following exception.

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
cannot serialize '_io.TextIOWrapper' object
...
line ... in ...
res = pool.map(self._count, dirs)
```

I found out, that this exception can occure when sharing resources betwenen processes, which - as far as I can see - I only do with `stats = dict.fromkeys(self._categories, 0)`. But replacing this line with hardcoded values won't fix the problem. Even placing a breakpoint at this line won't help me, because it isn't reached.

Does anybody have an idea what the reason for this problem is and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you try to transmit "self". If self has a Stream object it can't be serialized.

Try and move the multiprocessed code outside the class.

Python multiprocessing launches a new interpreter and if you try to access shared code that can't be pickled (or serialized) it fails. Usually it doesn't crash where you think it crashed... but when trying to recieve the object.
I converted a code using threads to multiprocessing and i had a lot of wierd errors even i didn't sent or used those objects, but i used their parent ( self )

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
I tried putting the code for the `_count` function and all functions that are called in it outside of the class, effecitfly making  them normal functions. But now I have the problem, that I don't know, how to give additional parameters to those functions, for example the list of all possible categorys. 
Do you know, how that can be achieved?

Comment: That is another problem althoghether.. you have to use Manager from multiprocessing amd Manager.queue/list or others... i didn't delve too much into that ... but Lock and Queue from there work. An u just transmit that as parameter when you add the job to the pool.

Comment: That if you want to modify those elements, if not just give them as parameters and python will make a copy